# ffmpeg youtube livestream not working

Tags: ffmpeg

Today i tried using ffmpeg on my debian 8.3 server to livestream 24/7 hours. However it doesnt work.

```
#! /bin/bash

INRES="1280x1024" # input resolution (The resolution of the program you want to stream!)
OUTRES="1024x790" # Output resolution (The resolution you want your stream to be at)
FPS="60" # target FPS
QUAL="ultrafast" 
# one of the many FFMPEG presets that can be used 
# If you have low bandwidth, put the qual preset on 'ultrafast' (upload bandwidth)
# If you have medium bandwitch put it on normal to medium or fast
STREAM_KEY="hidden" # this is your streamkey




ffmpeg -f "file.avi" -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :0.0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -vcodec libx264 -s "$OUTRES" \
-acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -threads 0 \
-f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
```

it gives me the output

Unknown input format: 'file.avi'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
ffmpeg -f "file.avi" ...
```

should be

```
ffmpeg -i "file.avi" ...
```